# Is possible to display a link to my website in gmail inbox

Tags: gmail, google-api

Is possible to display a link to my website in gmail inbox, I have a google business account.

I developed an API that first check user login, and then directing to a website, i want to display its link in gmail inbox

Comment: Gmail inbox? You mean like sending user an email with a link in it?

Comment: nop! I am talking about gamil inbox interface

Comment: I want to display that hyper-link on side bar or top menu

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via [Gmail Sidebar gadgets](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/gadgets/sidebar/).

To create a gadget with a simple link, you just create a gadget spec and make it available via a public Url. There is a [simple editor for Gadgets](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/legacy/gs.html#GGE).

Gmail gadgets can make requests to external services via `makeRequest()` function. If you need  user authentication then your [gadget must do OAuth authentication](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/oauth.html).